# HandleKeyPress not recognising down arrow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, accessibility

I'm in the process of building a customised, accessible `select` input with React.js. I need to have the `up` and `down` arrow keys function as the `tab` key would within the scope of `select` input's `option`s.

I have a `handleKeyPress` function on the elements that detects when other keys are pressed (for instance `'Enter'` works fine).

Here is an example `option`:

```
<li
  className="oc-select-field__item"
  tabIndex="0"
  onClick={handleClick}
  onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
>
```

...and here is the `handleKeyPress` function

```
handleKeyPress = event => {
  if (event.key === 40) {
    console.log('Down arrow key fired'); // does not fire
  }
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log('Enter key fired'); // does fire
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong that I am not successfully detecting when the `down` arrow is pressed?

Comment: You are mixing different `KeyboardEvent` properties. You can see the different properties and their values for the different types of keyboard events here: https://keyjs.dev

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`event.which` will give you the numeric value of the key.

`event.key` and `event.code` will give you a string value.

Try this tool: http://keycode.info

```
if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
    console.log('Down arrow key fired');
}
```

As @devserkan mentioned you should use `onKeyDown` instead of `onKeyPress`.

> The **keydown** event is fired when a key is pressed down. Unlike the keypress event, the keydown event is fired for keys that produce a character value **and for keys that do not produce a character value.**

Comment: Keep in mind some old browsers used some non-standard codes, so, for example, left is usually `'LeftArrow'` and right is `'RightArrow'`, but on IE and Legacy Edge they would be shown as `'Left'` and `'Right'` instead. Also, take a look at https://keyjs.dev. I will add information about these kinds of cross-browser incompatibilities soon! 

Answer (score 5):

For Arrow keys, I think you need `onKeyDown` instead of `onKeyPress`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  handleKeyPress = ( event ) => {
    if ( event.key === "ArrowDown" ) {
      console.log( "Down arrow key fired" ); // does not fire
    }
    if ( event.key === "Enter" ) {
      console.log( "Enter key fired" ); // does fire
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li
            tabIndex="0"
            onClick={this.handleClick}
            onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}
          >Foo
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind some old browsers used some non-standard codes, so, for example, left is usually `'LeftArrow'` and right is `'RightArrow'`, but on IE and Legacy Edge they would be shown as `'Left'` and `'Right'` instead. Also, take a look at https://keyjs.dev. I will add information about these kinds of cross-browser incompatibilities soon! 